# Java диалоговое окно в случае ошибки

Tags: java

Есть код запроса в удаленную БД. Как сделать так, чтобы в случае любой ошибки в этом участке кода появлялось окно с ошибкой, или хотя бы со стандартной фразой любого содержания? Чтобы пользователь понял, что что-то не так. и соответственно, чтобы implements ActionListener не выполнялся.

```
public static class mysql implements ActionListener{
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
        ScheduledFuture<?> future = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> actionPerformed(null), 1, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

        private static String url = "jdbc:mysql://";
        private static String user = "";
        private static String password = "";



        private static Connection con;
        private static Statement stmt;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){


            try {
            ownip = Getip.getip();
            gettime = Gettime.getip();
                    } catch (IOException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        StringBuilder lp = List.list();
        try {


            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            String sql =  "zapros";

            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = con.prepareStatement(sql);

            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
            sqlEx.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }

}
```

код смены лого кнопки:

```
    Start.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            String icon = (Start.isSelected()) ? "/PFP/button_off.png" :"/PFP/button_on.png";
            Start.setIcon(new ImageIcon(gui.class.getResource(icon)));

        }
    });
```

Comment: Выдача окна с ошибкой зависит от типа используемой оконной системы: на Swing это одна история, на SWT другая, на Android третья... определитесь с оконной системой сначала

Comment: @ Barmaley, я использовал windows builder, он на Swing  на сколько я понимаю

Answer (score 2):

Во первых (не обязательно но желательно) имя класса с большой буквы
Во вторых, в приведенном примере один метод в котором все происходит в try catch и если вы хотите выводить сообщения об ошибке, то делайте это в блоке catch, или создайте метод который вы там будете вызывать
И в Третьих, что Вы имеете в виду под формулировкой

> чтобы implements ActionListener не выполнялся

Comment: > чтобы implements ActionListener не выполнялся. Неверно сформулировал. При нажатии на кнопку, выполняется этот класс и кнопка меняет свое лого. Класс и кнопка связаны ActionListener. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы в случае ошибки кнопка не менялась на другу.

Comment: @Drop Путаете формулировку, класс не может выполниться или нет, выполняется метод, конечно можно не менять кнопку, самого кода меняющего кнопку я не увидел, но во первых поместите код меняющий кнопку в самый конец блока try, и если какой то метод (Ваши executeUpdate и пр.) упадет, то выполнение всего блока перейдет в блок catch, и кнопка не изменится

Comment: Так же в блоке catch вызывайте ваше окно которое говорит пользователю об ошибке

Comment: код смены лого добавил. Про добавление в try я попробую, спасибо

Comment: @Drop, Ага, у вас смена кнопки в другом слушателе, а чем вызвано такое решение, почему бы вам не добавлять метод как слушатель отдельно а вызывать его в конце блока try метода  actionPerformed класса mysql  ? (не знаю специфики Swing  сам пишу desktop на JavaFx)

Comment: Сделал так, потому как в java недавно. И делал, как говориться, "хоть как-то". Поэтому и в другом слушателе. Попробую сделать как вы написали)